# groovy List comparisons

Tags: list, groovy

I have a list with 4 directories example:

```
[dir1,dir2/dir3,dir4,dir7]
```

Then I have a second list:
These are full full filenames with paths

```
[dir1/file1.txt,dir8/file2.ext,dir4/dir5/dir6/file4.ext, dir2/dir3/file4.ext]
```

I want to find the intersection and in this case return:

```
[dir1,dir4,dir2/dir3]
```

Comment: what happens if `dir1` is just part of the path?  ie: `dir6/dir1/file.txt` should that match as it has `dir1` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are lists of strings.

And assuming you just want to know if the 4 directories *prefix* the second list entries.

And assuming you don't have some requirement to use a regex

And you have the two lists in variables like this:

```
def a = ['dir1','dir2/dir3','dir4','dir7']
def b = ['dir1/file1.txt','dir8/file2.ext','dir4/dir5/dir6/file4.ext', 'dir2/dir3/file4.ext']
```

Then you can do:

```
def result = a.findAll {first ->
    b.any { it.startsWith(first) }
}
```

Comment: startsWith is the way! tyvm again!  this is drastically going to improve pipelines for me!